# Translation table for converting gcc compilation/link options to icc

Tags: c++, gcc, icc

For testing I would like to switch from using GCC to ICC for compiling my C/CXX-code. During compilation I am using command line options such as `-mavx -march=native`, which are set in my CMakeLists-file with

```
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC -mavx -march=native)
```

Now I also know that I have to replace `-mavx` in GCC with `-xavx` for ICC, but I do not know what I can use for the other compilation/link parameters. Is there a translation table between the options for GCC and ICC?

Comment: Aren't the ICC options documented somewhere? If you read the GCC documentation for `-march`, doesn't the ICC documentation list something similar?

Comment: It's not only -march, but also options like '-fPIC -flto -O3 -funroll-loops' and others, and I imagine that it's simpler to have a direct translation table than having to go through the documentation for both GCC and ICC.

Comment: ICC also has a `-march` flag, but native is not an option, you need to either specify the hardware architecture or the instruction set you want to target i.e. `-march=core-avx2`. [Docs here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/compiler-options/alphabetical-list-of-compiler-options.html). I don't know of any mechanism to translate flags between compilers.Also, ICC `/O2` flag may not perform the same optimisation as GCC's `/O2`, so not obvious how a translation would work.

Comment: But you are in luck because most of those flags you mentioned have direct equivalents for ICC.